# Who or what is Monica and why so much notice from SE users?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, community

I see more and more users putting profile names related to "Monica". Is there an official post of what is all this movement around "Monica"?

Comment: here's the summary: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper

Comment: I'd say, at this point, the quickest path to a TL;DR summary is [this news article on The Register](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/08/stack_overflow_apology/).

Comment: @MartijnPieters FWIW they also posted an update article [discussed here at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341572/165773). "Stack Overflow makes peace with ousted moderator, wants to start New Year with 2020 vision on codes of conduct"

Comment: She was fired due to something she said in private communication with the company regarding the new rules on personal pronouns. The company said they had good reason to believe that she would not enforce/follow the rules based on what she said. Monica says this isn’t true. Neither side has posted a transcript of that conversation.

Comment: You can find the information about it, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/stack-overflow-is-doing-me-ongoing-harm-its-time-to-fix-it) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342039/firing-community-managers-stack-exchange-is-not-interested-in-cooperating-with/342950#342950).

Comment: (OK, the intent wasn't to bump it. It was linked from [a comment](https://arstechnica.com/civis/threads/after-chatgpt-disruption-stack-overflow-lays-off-28-percent-of-staff.1496474/post-42275094) to the 2023-10-16 [Ars Technica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars_Technica) article *"[After ChatGPT disruption, Stack Overflow lays off 28 percent of staff](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2023/10/after-chatgpt-disruption-stack-overflow-lays-off-28-percent-of-staff/)"*.)

Answer (score 157):

The best summary that you can get is over on MSE - [Summing up the main issues (The Story So Far)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334399/summing-up-the-main-issues-the-story-so-far). A Tl;DR is:

Monica was a moderator on 6 different sites and was a highly decorated moderator. She had contributed frequently to the growth of the entire Stack Exchange community and was appointed as a moderator on MSE in recognition of that. She was fired after she requested clarifications on a new policy and a change in the CoC. Here is her version of the story: [Stack Overflow Inc., sinat chinam, and the goat for Azazel](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/stack-overflow-inc-sinat-chinam-and-the-goat-for-azazel)
.

A lot of moderators then resigned due to the way Stack Exchange treated her. [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper). Stack Exchange later  spoke about her in newspapers. The Director and CTO of Stack Exchange later posted public apologies, but didn't do anything to follow up their apologies. Finally after taking the legal route ([Stack Overflow is doing me ongoing harm; it's time to fix it!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/stack-overflow-is-doing-me-ongoing-harm-its-time-to-fix-it)), Monica was able to sign off on an agreement ([Update: an agreement with Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio)), which wasn't *that* helpful.

Later on, Stack Exchange fired a couple of Community Managers (who work for the company) which started another set of moderator resignations. [Firing Community Managers: Stack Exchange is not interested in cooperating with the community, is it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342039/firing-community-managers-stack-exchange-is-not-interested-in-cooperating-with). These two community managers were known to be very deeply involved with the community, which makes this issue a bit more complex. (This is where we are now)

Comment: Something which people haven't mentioned earlier is that Monica was #2 on Stack Moderators Teams.

Comment: Also, something that apparently a lot of people miss is that the problem with Monica isn't about Monica. In that it's not a single error or misjudgement SE did. There has been a growing problem for literal years. The actions SE took against Monica would in no way be justified even without previous missteps however, *combined* with them it was the catalist for a drastic shift in opinion about the management. It is sort of the straw that broke the camel's back...but we already had a full load of straws, this was an entire log dropped on the poor animal.

Comment: It's fair to say this series of missteps will soon become the subject of textbooks.

Comment: @theMayer: "... and that was how Stack Overflow ended. Our next case study is ..."

Comment: @YorSubs: Without reading the original transcript and from puzzling things together from here and there over time, my understanding is that Monica argued that writing in a gender neutral way should be allowed (i.e., not using any pronouns by default). The first version of the CoC explicitly did not allow for this which is why this was discussed. In the revised CoC, gender neutral writing is accepted but this revision came first after Monica was fired and the events that followed. At that point in time, there were already a lot of other issues, e.g. how SE handled the whole situation.

Comment: Nice summary. Now it is visible the sad truth: what the company did, this summarized, **is not fixable**, it does not mean how strongly and long do they work on it. But they don't even really try, except some very pathetic lip service, from which everybody knows that it is only cheap lie. The consequences are obvious.

Comment: @peterh Not only that, but what they did is a NORMAL corporate policy. Many corporations did similar things,thogh it rare was this visible. Another example would be removal  of employees by Linden Lab (Second Life social network). A manager or officer "deeply involved" with community is a risk for corporate interests, and by being recognised so they automatically draw crosshairs on themselves when a policy change is expected. But usually corps are being moreclever and can find some other excuses for firing.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I see, that is how big companies normally work, but I don't believe that it should be allowed. We have a free market, we are free to cease connection with such a company.

Comment: @peterh apologists of free market forget that patents, DMCA, non-competing agreements and natural monopoly are antagonistical to concept of "free".

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I do not. But look, how people is thinking and argumenting here. The community, what the company has collected here, is imho essentially antagonistical to anything what could be labeled as free (as in freedom). They do not understand that we do not need to be evil, and they understand yet lesser why we should not be. Note, actually I do not remember also Monica as a nice mod here, she was one of the worsts, I only sided with her because it was simply... disgusting what they did to her. But it was more an infight between two evils, imho.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I think, SE does not use any of these (patents, DMCA, agreement). They are using, more clearly: misusing social inertia. It might qualify as "natural monopoly". The important thing is that while there is the SE, its alternative - even if it is better - can not grow strong simply because no one learns that it exists. They started codidact, it has imho no real chance (beside that, they have already now copied many inherent fault (sin) of the SE). But misusing social inertia is a legal thing, yet, but it should not be. Once the Bell monopoly was legal, too...

Comment: @peterh right, social inertia combined with market ideosincrasy (why try to compete with a giant if you can try something else?) creates a form of monopoly. Just by having no competition. NCA is used by almost EVERY big IT company. And many tech companies in general. On other hand, forming such a monopoly, the misues of said inertia becomes asecond nature.

Answer (score -13):

The Meta forums should all have a Monica tag... the fact that there isn't (and won't be) one is a testament to the fundamental problem with Stack Exchange: Incentives are not aligned between the corporation and the community (which is the core cause of all the problems, Monica among them).

Seek aligned incentives (in life and business). Everything misaligned results in friction and at times fracture.

**UPDATE**

This thread is an example of toxicity and willful deafness. "Monica" is a poor name for a tag. OK, then suggest one better that actually hooks to the issue as it is popularly known. "Company" and "Community" may mean something to those (few) of you "in the know" (e.g. who know that those tags relate to the blow up and mass resignations of moderators). For the rest of us, the Monica incident was our entre to the topic (which we know is much larger than that one incident).

I, and the OP, and other posters here, may be misguided noobs (or whatever we are). But we come to this thread honestly and simply. The hostility directed to my post (and at least one other on this thread) is a symptom of the problem. Y'all could use these posts to explain and build. To start with an assumption of positive intent. But instead y'all choose to downvote, degrade, and mis-engage.

Hope it makes you happy.

Comment: This is nonsense. There is nothing stopping moderators or even regular users from creating a [[meta-tag:monica]] tag. Staff has done nothing to prevent that. However, I do not feel that this tag would serve any purpose. We don't need to continue discussing Monica; there is nothing more that can be done about that. For discussions about the relationship between the company and the community, we have two tags: [[meta-tag:community]] and [[meta-tag:company]] (the latter of which is a synonym of [[meta-tag:stack-exchange]]).

Comment: I think you are missing the underlying conversation. There is an issue, that came to a head with the Monica incident. A Monica tag is not to talk about the Monica incident, it would be to tag discussions related to the overall issue of misaligned management behavior and attitude toward moderators/the community. "Monica" is simply the tag, not the topic itself.

Comment: That is a poor name for the tag, as the issues are unrelated to Monica herself. They are much larger than that. Monica's dismissal and the subsequent bungling of the issue by staff members was only a *symptom* of the larger problem. We do need to talk about the problem, that's why I pointed out the two tags, both of which were expressly created for this purpose. But we do not need to plaster discussions about it with Monica's name. She never asked for that, and it would not help to make those discussions discoverable.

Comment: @CodyGray So suggest a better name for a tag that is understandable by those (many) of us who know that the Monica incident is one part of a larger whole, but have no idea (and never will) that "community" and "company" are tied to the larger issue. My suggestion is weak? Fine. Perhaps try to come up with a tag that has meaning (for the OP, for me, for the many who were introduced to the issue via the Monica fiasco) rather than going on a rant.  But hey, it is your community. Treat it how you like to be treated.

Comment: Hi - I'm not being toxic by simply disagreeing with your assessment of the circumstance, or disagreeing with you wanting a tag for this.  This is even more in the case that the person involved herself didn't want a Meta tag created.

Comment: Web culture would create a new word for incidents by appending"gate", such as Monicagate.

Comment: @tkruse Excellent point. Agreed. And if the letters "monica" are too messy to touch, this could be "ModeratorGate2019" or something that is narrow enough to specify the concrete eruption, yet broad enough to capture the broad scale and impact  of the event.

Comment: @tkruse - [appending _gate_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_%22-gate%22_scandals) to a scandalous event that ultimately led to a media frenzy, or otherwise gained cultural awareness is far older than _web culture_.  :)  ([or is it?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_culture))

Comment: This rant doesn't provide any answer to the question that was actually asked.

Answer (score -25):

The interesting part of your question is “why so much notice from Stack Exchange users”.

Specifically, the mass name change, which is a cheap, easy and relatively effort-free way for a small number of users who are very active on the site to spread their message to a large number of users.

The truth is that 99% or more of users neither know nor care who Monica is or was, namely a fairly senior moderator and  community manager or whatever for the site.

The reasons that the 1% or fewer people who do know who she is, those that were impacted or affected and knew about the story through site gossip—you know, the Great Scandal of Stack Exchange 2019—the reasons that *those* people care, or pretend to care, and choose to show this by changing their name to some variation of “reinstate Monica” are many and varied.

Firstly, there are some genuine misguided souls out there who truly believe that it’s important to have fair and transparent rules that govern website moderation, with the same level of scrutiny given to moderator law it as, say, the attorney general’s office or the federal reserve. They have a cause to champion, and they’re never happier than when they have that, and especially if they can visibly “contribute” to said cause by expending zero physical or monetary effort.

Secondly, there are people who are or were personal friends and acquaintances of Monica, those who had met her in the [meatspace](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meatspace#Noun) and had some kind of personal connection with her. They would have at least an excuse to change their name to some Monica-related name, to show solidarity with their [IRL](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/IRL#Adverb) friend.

Thirdly, a lot of people just like joining in with stuff just for the hell of it.

I guess there’s more reasons, virtue signalling, contrarianism, wanting to be seen as someone who “sticks it to the man”. Like I said, this is by far the more interesting part of your question than “what happen Monica, why Monica sad?”, which is sadly what the majority of people get fixated on.