# What has happened in the past few months?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

Personally, I am not quite active on Meta although I consider myself quite active on StackOverflow. And I believe there are many users like me. Having said that and given the fact that Moderator Elections for 2020 are approaching, I wanted to clarify a couple of things.

I've read a couple of discussions (for example, [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398884/2020-moderator-election-qa-question-collection)) on meta since yesterday that were talking about conflicts between users. And I've seen a lot of users mentioning "what has happened in the past few months" without going into any details. And I am quite interested in understanding what exactly the conflict was and how it ended as I believe this is quite relevant to the upcoming elections.

PS: I just have an honest intention to understand what has happened. I don't have any intention to bring up conflicts between members.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who or what is Monica and why so much notice from SE users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393046/who-or-what-is-monica-and-why-so-much-notice-from-se-users). It’s a very long story that involves a ton of context, and it’s not just about Monica.

Comment: Also, the relevant question at Meta SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965

Comment: Plus [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334399/282465)

Comment: Understanding what happened is a lot easier said than done, not gonna lie. It started with a CoC change and a mod being fired, it extended into a licensing mess and a full-on conflict with the company that we're still dealing with to some degree to this day, even if the bulk of the drama has calmed down. There's quite a lot of reading material on all the different issues - if you plan on reading everything, you probably have enough reading material for a week or two

Comment: @Zoe Nitpicking (:;): Probably because the issues surrounding Monica and the CoC change are such a large, important part of everything that went on, you've got the order of some things incorrect, and (understandably) elide for brevity other issues leading up to Monica and that CoC change. I'm mostly reacting to saying it *started* with Monica and the CoC change. IMO, it's more accurate to say things had been on edge well before they blew up with Monica and the CoC change, but the issues didn't *start* there. It is, however, a good demarcation for the increase in the intensity of the issues.

Comment: @Makyen I tried including more, but it's hard getting everything in 600 characters or less without leaving out details. Some issues have been around for years, but arguably the start of the major issues was with Monica. It escalated with the home page and HMP issues, but it really started there (in my opinion though, to be clear). But yeah, the situation is very complex :')

Comment: Actually, I just randomly happened to be reminded of this project made by Samuel Liew: https://stackexchange-timeline.webflow.io - jump to 2018 and scroll up. It summarizes a lot of the main events